# Android XML Layout: get the image view to stay directly on the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create an app that has a scroll view filled with buttons and an image view on the bottom. The only problem is that I can't get the image view to stay directly on the bottom. I tried setting layout_gravity and gravity to the bottom but the image is off of the screen. I do not want to use weight because there are custom buttons and it would distort them. I have tried both relative layout and frame layout with no avail (I might not be using them correctly). With this set up, the bottom is visible at the top but not at the bottom.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="320.0dip"
    android:layout_height="50.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logopublic" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/red" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@drawable/green" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/button1"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/button3"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the bottom is visible at the top not at the bottom' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the relativeLayout to surround your imagevire and scrollview. Then specify the attributes in XML:  alignparentbottom="true" and above="your_imageview" for the scrollview and alignparentbottom="true" and below="your_scrollview" for the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`.

I know you don't want to user `android:gravity="bottom"`, but if you do and set the height to `android:height="wrap_content"` it shouldn't distort your images.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
add android:weightSum="10" to the top linearLayout.
Then add android:weight="7" to ImageView and android:weight=3 to ScrollView.
Change heights and widths of those Views to fill_parent